# zod - How to deepPick

Tags: javascript, typescript, fastify, zod

I am using zod with fastify. I have a UserModel that consists of the username and device properties. The username field is a string, while the device field is an object (DeviceModel) with "name", "id" and "verified" fields.

During the sign-up process, I want to return the complete user object, but without including certain properties nested inside the DeviceModel. To achieve this, I aim to create a UserSignUpResponse. However, I do not want the entire DeviceModel to be included in the response. I have devised the following solution:

```js
const UserSignUpResponse = UserModel.pick({
  username: true,
  // unable to perform the following action
  device: DeviceModel.pick({
    id: true,
    name: true,
    verified: false,
  })
});
```

My question is whether I should ".pick fields from the UserModel schema and extend it with a device field with the same properties as the DeviceModel ?

Answer (score 1):

Nested pick is not allowed, but you can bypass that with the use of `extend`:

```js
const UserSignUpResponse = UserModel.pick({
  username: true,
}).extend({
  device: DeviceModel.pick({
    id: true,
    name: true,
    verified: false,
  })
})
```